# What can I mix soy protein isolate with so it tastes better?

Tags: veganism, protein, recipe-request, soy, sports

To follow a diet compatible with the type of physical activity that I do when training, I take more than a 100 g of protein per day.

As a vegan, I could get tricky to reach this amount while staying below the calorie count and carbohydrate amounts. One of the solutions is to drink protein shakes.

Unflavored soy isolate protein tastes frankly terrible. Besides bananas (that works!)

**What else can I mix into it to make it more palatable?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pinnaple juice (or mixed fruit) is a great alternative. Other fruits might also work but stay away from apples as it thickens too much.

You definitely want to try add some ice into the mixer. A chilled soy shake seems to make a big difference, the same applies to non-vegan shakes. I can't really find a good source for this claim, but temperature has a play in taste,  just as cold coffee taste s worse.